# A group $U_{2^{\infty}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across an example of a group $U_{2^{\infty}}$. It's a group of complex roots of power $p^n$ where $p$ is primal and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have a question: why is a group?

If $n$ is fixed then obviously but then I don't understand why we write $2^{\infty}$. But if $n$ not fixed I don't get why it's a group.

Answer (score 4):

This group is also called the Prüfer $2$-group, and can be denoted $C_{2^{\infty}}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{\infty}}$. We write it like this because it can be shown to be the [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) of the cyclic groups $C_{2^n}$ under the canonical embeddings $C_{2^n}\hookrightarrow C_{2^{n+1}}$, so thinking of it as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}C_{2^n}$$
naturally leads to the notation $C_{2^{\infty}}$ (replace "$C_{2^n}$" with "$U_{2^n}$" for the notation you are using).

It consists of all complex numbers $z$ such that there exists a positive integer $n$ for which $z^{2^n}=1$.

It is a group: it is nonempty, since it contains $1$ (which satisfies $1^{2^1}=1$).

If $z$ and $w$ are in $C_{2^{\infty}}$, then there exist positive integers $n$ and $m$ such that $z^{2^n}=1$ and $w^{2^m}=1$. Then taking $k=n+m$ we have that
$$(zw)^{2^k} = z^{2^k}w^{2^k} = (z^{2^{n+m}})(w^{2^{n+m}}) = (z^{2^n})^{2^m}(w^{2^m})^{2^n} = 1^{2^m}1^{2^n}=1,$$
so $zw\in C_{2^{\infty}}$.

And if $z\in C_{2^{\infty}}$ with $z^{2^n}=1$, then $(z^{-1})^{2^n} = (z^{2^n})^{-1} = 1^{-1} = 1$, so $z^{-1}\in C_{2^{\infty}}$.

Thus, this is a group under multiplication.